# How can I check in an Eclipse project unused libraries dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to convert to maven, a project in Eclipse which has a lot of external jars added manually to build path. 
I would like to "clean" the project and check what externals jars added are really called, either by a source or by an internal jar dependency, and avoid adding dependencies to my pom.xml which will be useless.

Is there a tool for doing this ?

Thank you if anyone has a clue.

Comment: Why dont you let Maven decide what jars are required and what jars are not required? Are they not managed by Maven?

Answer (score 0):

So just so we're clear, you haven't converted your project yet, you just need to understand its dependencies?

Assuming that's true, I would first make a copy of your ".classpath" file.

Then go into your project properties, and in the "Libraries" tab, remove all the libraries, except for perhaps the JVM library.

Save that, and inspect the results.  Your resulting red marks throughout the project should help you map your dependencies.

Comment: No, what I want is a tool able to check source code and say what librairies are really necessary, including at runtime.